# SED search and replace substring in a database file

Tags: sed

To all,

I have spent alot of time searching for a solution to this but cannot find it.

Just for a background, I have a text database with thousands of records. Each record is delineated by :

"0 @nnnnnn@ Xnnn"    // no quotes

The records have many fields on a line of their own, but the field I am interested in to search and replace a substring (notice spaces) :

"   1 X94 User1.faculty.ventura.ca"     // no quotes

I want to use sed to change the substring ".faculty.ventura.ca" to ".students.moorpark.ut", changing nothing else on the line, globally for ALL records.

I have tested many things with negative results.

How can this be done ?

Thank You for the assistance.
Bob Perez (robertperez1957@gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want this:

```
sed 's/1 X94 \(.*\).faculty.ventura.ca/1 X94 \1.students.moorpark.ut/' mydatabase.file
```

This will replace all records of the form `1 X94 XXXXXX.faculty.ventura.ca` with `1 X94 XXXXX.students.moorpark.ut`.

Here's details on what it all does:

- The `''` let you have spaces and other messes in your script.
- `s/`  means substitute
- `1 X94 \(.*\).faculty.ventura.ca`  is what you'll be substituting.  The `\(.*\)` stores anything in that regular expression for use in the replacement
- `1 X94 \1.students.moorpark.ut`   is what to replace the thing you found with.  \1 is filled in with the first thing that matched `\(.*\)`.  (You can have multiple of those in one line, and the next one would then be \2.)
- The final `/` just tells sed that you're done.  If your database doesn't have linefeeds to separate its records, you'll want to end with `/g`, to make this change multiple times per line.
- mydatabase.file should be the filename of your database.

Note that this will output to standard out.  You'll probably want to add

```
> mynewdatabasefile.name
```

to the end of your line, to save all the output in a file.  (It won't do you much good on your terminal.)

#### Edit, per your comments

If you want to replace `1 F94 bperez.students.Napvil.NCC` to `1 F94 bperez.JohnSmith.customer`, you can use another set of `\(.*\)`, as:

```
sed 's/1 X94 \(.*\).\(.*\).Napvil.NCC/1 X94 \1.JohnSmith.customer/' 251-2.txt
```

This is similar to the above, except that it matches two stored parameters.  In this example, `\1` evaluates to `bperez` and `\2` evaluates to `students`.  We match `\2`, but don't use it in the replace part of the expression.
You can do this with any number of stored parameters.  (Sed probably has some limit, but I've never hit a sufficiently complicated string to hit it.)  For example, we could make the sed script be `'\(.\) \(...\) \(.*\).\(.*\).\(.*\).\(.*\)/\1 \2 \3.JohnSmith.customer/'`, and this would make \1 = 1, \2 = X94, \3 = bperez, \4 = Napvil and \5 = NCC, and we'd ignore \4 and \5.  This is actually not the best answer though - just showing it can be done.  It's not the best because it's uglier, and also because it's more accepting.  It would then do a find and replace on a line like `2 Z12 bperez.a.b.c`, which is presumably not what you want.  The find query I put in the edit is as specific as possible while still being general enough to suit your tasks.

#### Another edit!

You know how I said "be as specific as possible"?  Due to the `.` character being special, I wasn't.  In fact, I was very generic.  The `.` means "match any character at all," instead of "match a period".  Regular expressions are "greedy", matching the most they could, so `\(.*\).\(.*\)` will always fill the first `\(.*\)`  (which says, "take 0 to many of any character and save it as a match for later") as far as it can.
Try using:

```
    sed 's/1 X94 \(.*\)\.\(.*\).Napvil.NCC/1 X94 \1.JohnSmith.customer/' 251-2.txt
```

That extra `\` acts as an escape sequence, and changes the `.` from "any character" to "just the period".  FYI, since I don't (but should) escape the other periods, technically sed would consider `1 X94 XXXX.StdntZNapvilQNCC` as a valid match.  Since `.` means any character, a Z or a Q there would be considered a fit.

Comment: Scott, it worked perfectly.  However I forgot to mention that

Comment: Comment 1 of 2:

Scott, it worked perfectly.  However I forgot to mention that I have the possibility of 5 different names 
before ".Napvil.NCC" - Notice the case. 

I made up some of the text for privacy before, it is really the below information :

I have the possibility of 5 different scenarios with this field in the records :

1.  "  1 F94 bperez.stdnts.Napvil.NCC"        //No quotes for all
2.  "  1 F94 BJohnson.Stdnts.Napvil.NCC"
3.  "  1 F94 WLasson.OthrUsr.Napvil.NCC"
4.  "  1 F94 DPalmer.Faclty.Napvil.NCC"
5.  "  1 F94 IMessenger.Admstr.Napvil.NCC"

Comment: Comment 2 of 2:  I need to change all of these possiblities to be : 
  
   "  1 F94 UniqueUserName.JohnSmith.customer" 
   
   instead of what you see above, 1-5, AFTER " 1 F94 UserName."
   
I used:

sed 's/1 F94 \(.*\).Napvil.NCC/1 F94 \1.JohnSmith.customer/' 251-2.txt
 
The above sed command gets me :
    1 F94 BJohnson.stdnts.JohnSmith.customer
 

Thank You for you fine help on this,

Bob Perez, robertperez1957@gmail.com

Comment: Scott :With this SED commmand :
 
 sed 's/1 F94 \(.*\).\(.*\).Napvil.NCC/1 F94 \1.JeffSchopp.customer/' 251-2.txt


I go from:
  1 F94 User1.Stdnt.Napvil.NCC
  
To:
  1 F94 User1.Stdnt.JohnSmith.customer
  
  
 I need it to say:
   1 F94 User1.JohnSmith.customer
   
   Note: I assuem the case of the letters don't factor into this ?
   
   
   With the SED command :
   
    sed 's/1 F94 \(.*\).\(.*\).\(.*\).Napvil.NCC/1 F94 \1.JeffSchopp.customer/' 251-2.txt
    
    I get the same results as above ...
    
    Not sure what can be done frome here...
    
    Thanks, Bob Perez

Comment: Since we're using the `.`, which matches any character, case shouldn't matter.  Your previous comment doesn't show any \'s.  If you didn't enter those in, that would cause issues.  If you did, could you please edit the comment to show them?  Thanks.  In testing, I see that the backslashes don't appear in comments, unless you double them up:  sed 's/1 F94 \\(.*\\)  uses two on each one.  Or, use the backwards-apostrophe code indicator, and then you only need one:  `sed 's/1 F94 \(.*\)` etc.  I see a potential problem in the script I gave.  I'll have an edit up shortly.

Comment: Scott, Thank you for your excellent help.  Your last suggestion did  the trick, it works great.

Comment: Great!  If you're happy with it, I'll get more reputation if you click the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial helped me 
[sed - replace substring in file](http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/01/sed-command-in-unix-examples.html)

try the same using a **-i** prefix to replace in the file directly

> sed -i 's/unix/linux/' file.txt